# Unity 2D. Прилипание к стенам во время прыжка

Tags: unity3d, 2d

у меня есть небольшая проблема, когда я в Юнити сделал прыжок, то у меня персонаж стал прилипать к стенам. Я пошел гуглить и нашел вариант решения проблемы с помощью убирания трения у коллайдера, но он мне не совсем подходит, по тому что из-за этого на вот таких поверхностях [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

объект начинает сам подниматься, хотя в теории не должен бы. Вопрос в том, как исправить прилипание к стенам и чтобы объект сам не забирался на конусы? Или лучше посоветуйте как можно переделать прыжок чтобы не фигачить такие костыли

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать слои в Unity2d ("Layer") подробней прочитай здесь: https://unityhub.ru/manual/Layers . Проще говоря это какие игровые объекты могут взаимодействовать с различными функциями и друг с другом.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)